# Synonymize [flags] and [flagging] on Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

The [flags](/questions/tagged/flags) and [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging) tags on Meta actually have the same purpose: for questions about flagging.

Could someone synonymize them?

Comment: Done the easy way.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thanks!

Comment: Also made flagging a proper synonym so trying to tag with it will add flags instead.